# why is parse.com is referencing the incorrect current user when saving data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

When I run the below code, the username thats captured looks like an old deleted user and therefore pointers are not created correctly. However when I run it from jfiddle the correct username is captured.

I've tried deleting the file, dumping cache etc.

I don't understand why/who its referencing the old user and how to stop this happening?

I'm definitely logged in as the right user.

The only thing I could thing of, is its within a sub folder to the main code, perhaps the user name is not being captured because of that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("xxx", "xxx");
    var MyBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
    var userbadges = new MyBadges();
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#send").click(function () {

            var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect .go').attr("src");
            userbadges.set("BadgeName", badgeselected);
            //userbadges.set("username", user); 
            userbadges.set("username", currentUser);
            console.log("done");
            console.log(currentUser);

            userbadges.save(null, {
                success: function (results) {
                    // The object was saved successfully.
                    console.log(currentUser);

                    //location.reload();
                },
                error: function (contact, error) {
                    // The save failed.
                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $('.go').click(function (e) { // Button which will activate our modal
            $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');


            $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                animation: 'fade', // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                animationspeed: 600, // how fast animtions are
                closeonbackgroundclick: true, // if you click background will modal close?
                dismissmodalclass: 'close' // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal


            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting the myBadges class and rebuilding it.